# Timestamping images in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know ROR appends a timestamp by default for my assets. But is this only the case if I use asset helpers? Does Rails append a timestamp if I add an img src tag manually, ie

```
<img src ="blah.gif">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this `blah.gif` in your `public` directory instead. Then use the `image` tag.